# What is the purpose of the hole in the top of an LD1117V33?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I'm planning on using an [LD1117V33](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/526) with input from the Raspberry Pi 5V rail ([circuit diagram](http://www.instructables.com/id/Pandoras-Box-An-Internet-Radio-player-made-with/step6/Connecting-the-LCD/)), and (maybe because this is my first electronics project) the hole at the top of the LD1117V33 makes me think that it could be laid flat and fastened.

But given that regulators turn extra voltage into heat, is this ever done? Will the leads even remain sound after bending?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the TO-220 package of the LD1117 can certainly be lead-formed to place the heat sink tab (the metal part with the hole) flat on a circuit board, another way of using it is to bolt a heat-sink onto the metal tab while leaving the part standing upright:

[image]
<sub>*(Source: [Adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2012/08/28/new-product-to-220-clip-on-heatsink/))*</sub>

Similarly, in many applications the through-holes for the TO-220 part will be close to the edge of the board, so that the tab can be directly bolted to an outer metal casing for the device. Appropriate insulation in the form of a nylon sleeve and mica washer electrically isolates the metal of the heat-sink from the metal casing, while allowing heat transfer.

Answer (score 7):

You can bend the leads a few times but don't make a big habit of it because it will break.

The hole, as you kind-of guessed is for laying the device flat on a heatsink and bolting it down.

And yes, this is done a lot especially when it looks like the power dissipation is greater than 0.5W - the heatsink prevents the device warming up too much.

Answer (score 4):

This is commonly done.

[image]

Depending on your heat needs, you don't need a separate heatsink to add on, though you can have lay flat heatsinks. A large copper pour can be used as a heatsink itself, called a thermal pad. Some ICs even require it! (Pictured L390 H Bridge Motor Driver and LDO removed from Raspberry PI)
[image]
[image]

The leads arn't as fragile as you may think, a bend or three won't kill them. Just make sure to hold them and bend the far end, to prevent any stress to the body of the to-220.

Answer (score 1):

The hole is indeed intended for mounting the device to a heatsink or some other mechanical surface.

It is possible to lead-form TO-220 devices. The 'proper' way to do it is via a tool that holds the leads rigidly near the edge of the case and applies the bend below the pinch point, so that force isn't transmitted through the package to the wire bond or the die. Many manufacturers will specify a minimum distance from the edge of the package for lead forming.

We have several pneumatic lead-form tools at my office that pinch and bend the device in a single operation (insert, ca-CHUNK, remove). They're very handy and completely reliable. That being said, one can lead-form with pliers when in a pinch (pun intended) but when I do it, I usually use two pliers - one to hold the lead near the package, the other to perform the bend.